# Increasing/Decreasing waitForDuration( )?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am wondering if its possible to increase withForDuration( ) with a variable. Heres how I am trying to do it in short. This is also SpriteKit, and this is my first time with it so I am still a little unsure. While this snippet of code works to change the float it doesn't actually change the waitForDuration(difficulty)

```
var timer: NSTimer!
var difficulty = 1.0


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

    player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.25)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: player.size.width/2)
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

    addChild(player)

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "increaseDifficulty", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy),
            SKAction.waitForDuration(difficulty)
            ])
        ))
}

func increaseDifficulty() {
  difficulty -= 0.1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `completionHandler` of the `runAction function`. For example.

```
func addEnemyWithChangingDifficulty() {

    let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(difficulty)
    let addEnemyAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
        self.addEnemy()
    }

    runAction(SKAction.sequence([addEnemyAction,waitAction]), completion: { () -> Void in
        self.addEnemyWithChangingDifficulty()
    })
}
```

Another way would be to use the `update function` to track the `waitDuration`.

```
var lastAddedTime : CFTimeInterval = 0

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if currentTime - lastAddedTime > CFTimeInterval(difficulty) {
        addEnemy()
        lastAddedTime = currentTime
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the second way and it works just how I like it! @rakeshbs

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting your intended effect because the value of 'difficulty' is captured in the first declaration of your SKAction and it never refers to the outside declaration again.

Two ways to solve this:

Instead of doing `SKAction.repeatActionForever()`, dump the `SKAction.sequence()` in increaseDifficulty. You'll have to tweak the numbers a bit to make it work, but NSTimer is already running on repeat, you can use that instead.

The second way (not 100% sure about this) is to put the '&' symbol in front of difficulty. This passes difficulty by reference rather by value, which should give you the intended effect. I'm just not sure if Swift allows this, but in C++ that's what we can do.

Comment: With my level of knowledge I wasn't able to figure out how to do this yet. I am still attempting to figure out the first way though! Thank you.